# geom_ribbon for variable levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some results of an analysis, in this case I am trying to fill with color the area bellow the black line which is a variable threshold. I have done something similar with `geom_ribbon` but considering a fixed threshold.

This is the data I am using:

```
 df <- data.frame(month= seq(560,624,1),
                     US= c(0.67,0.71,1.49,3.47,8.13,12.13,10.52,9.33,5.48,2.72,1.74,
                           0.16,0.04,0.15,0.76,0.94,10.60,26.50,15.09,17.93, 
                           15.68,11.69,7.00,3.68,0.46,0.55,1.21,4.14,12.73, 
                           10.24,10.89,22.13,18.76, 18.99,9.76,2.24,0.92,0.29, 
                           0.38,4.92,4.17,2.29,1.92,1.69, 14.87,12.32,2.00,0.67, 
                           0.12,0.06,0.80,4.41,6.70,18.61,7.21,43.62,23.64,12.83,
                           6.00,2.16,0.69,0.16,3.18,8.87,16.45),
                     lim= c(0.63,0.41,1.20,3.11,4.21,5.75,4.88,6.21,8.33,4.34,2.07,
                            1.16,0.63,0.41,1.20,3.11,4.21,5.75,4.88,6.21,8.33,4.34,
                            2.07,1.16,0.63,0.41,1.20,3.11,4.21,5.75,4.88,6.21,8.33,
                            4.34,2.07,1.16,0.63,0.41,1.20,3.11,4.21,5.75,4.88,6.21,
                            8.33,4.34,2.07,1.16,0.63,0.41,1.20,3.11,4.21,5.75,4.88,
                            6.21,8.33,4.34,2.07,1.16,0.63,0.41,1.20,3.11,4.21))


ggplot(df,aes(x=month,y=US)) +
  geom_line(col='deepskyblue4')+
  geom_line(aes(y=df[,'lim']))+
  theme_bw()
```

This is the original plot (in black the variable threshold)

[image: Original plot]

And this is what I am attempting to get with `geom_ribbon`, however I do not know how to do it:

[image]

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_ribbon`, if you set one of `ymin` or `ymax` to `NA` for those `x`-values you don't want to be filled:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = month, 
               ymin = ifelse(lim>US, lim, NA), 
               ymax = US, 
               y = US)) +
  geom_ribbon(fill = "pink") +
  geom_line(color = "deepskyblue4")+
  geom_line(aes(y = lim))+
  theme_bw()
```

**Edit:**
If you want to fill the gaps, you could interpolate the data for a nicer plot:

```
df_itpl <- data.frame(month = seq(min(df$month), max(df$month), .1))

df_itpl$US <- approx(x = df$month, y = df$US, xout = df_itpl$month)$y

df_itpl$lim <- approx(x = df$month, y = df$lim, xout = df_itpl$month)$y

ggplot(df_itpl, aes(x = month, 
               ymin = ifelse(lim>US, lim, NA), 
               ymax = US, 
               y = US)) +
  geom_ribbon(fill = "pink") +
  geom_line(color = "deepskyblue4")+
  geom_line(aes(y = lim))+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thank you Tino, but as I can see in the resulting plot, following this approach the edges of a filled area are not fully coloured. Maybe this issue is related to the established ymax and ymin. But it is a very useful solution too, I will keep on thinking on how to accurate this. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Marina which example do you mean? The Interpolation should at least approximately solve this issue. There you have the option to further decrese the step by setting the `by`-argument in `seq` to a smaller value (eg .01).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Tino. I referred to the first method you proposed before adding the interpolation which solves the problem of the edges now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_ribbon`, but first you need to process the data a little.

```
library(tidyverse)
#set US to lim if lim > US
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(US = if_else(lim > US, US, lim))


ggplot(df,aes(x=month,y=US)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = df2, aes(x = month, ymin = US, ymax = lim), fill = "pink") +
  geom_line(col='deepskyblue4')+
  geom_line(aes(y=lim))+      
  labs(title=paste('Station',sep=' '),x="Nº months", y = "Hm3",size=2)+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: In fact you overestimate the area at the limits, because of `lim > US`. Using `lim >= US` underestimates it. It's a first approach, but not totally correct.

Comment: Might need to interpolate data so that the cross-over point is more exact

Comment: @RichardTelford thank you so much for your help. It is true, as bVa mentions, that is not an exact method, but I can continue working on it from this point. Thank you once again.

Comment: @RichardTelford may I suggest that you refer to the `dplyr`-dependency or use `transform` and `ifelse`, such that it becomes more reproducible (or even less package-dependent in case of the latter)?